# Better CSS way for arranging divs

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have to add child div elements to #mainHolder div dynamically. There should be only three divs in a row. I am doing it using “**clear**” approach as shown in http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/ZkLg6/20/.

Is there a better CSS way for doing this?

Reference:

1. http://jsfiddle.net/Lijo/bSchQ/9/

Comment: I think that's fine for what you're doing. You could wrap a,b,c in a div with overflow: hidden; but I think what you're doing is fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may add `clear: left;` to your `.firstDiv` class. This way you will not need to add another div with `clear:both;` [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/25/) is an updated JSfiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `display: inline-block;` for the inner divs to make them coexist in a row.

This is your example, a bit rewritten, that does this:

http://jsfiddle.net/bSchQ/3/

Explanation:

- Javascript - that part is almost functionally identical to your, but I have rewritten it to be a bit more generic as an exercise. I wrap each row inside a seperate div to divide them.
- CSS - this is the important part. Let's say that I took your example and ONLY removed the `float: left`. Because of the `display: inline;` the divs will still render in the same row, but for the same reason they can't have a dimension (width, height). If you would declare them as `display: inline-block`, you get the best of both world. An inline element that you can place horizontally, and an element you can dimension yourself.

Comment: This is interesting. Can you please explain the logic in plain English?

Comment: Interesting solution, but additional wrapper div to make new rows... JS logic became more complicated because of it.

Comment: @FAngel: Well, the idea of such a markup is that one row really does convey some meaningful semantics, while an empty div doesn't really. This may or may not be a problem for you, but the company I currently work for is pretty picky about accessibility issues and code quality.

Comment: @Zuza More complicated (easier to make a mistake) logic is better? And... not clear how wrapping div helps with accessibility of dynamically created elements (search engines will not run that JS).

Comment: accessibility as in blind (like JAWS)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps set position to absolute and the width of your box to 150 e.g. 3 * 50px.

Check this link >> http://jsfiddle.net/ZkLg6/24/